# Javascript syntax need some explanation

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I am reading Javascript the Good Parts and came across the following snippet under Chapter 5 Inheritance:

```
var coolcat = function (spec) {
   var that = cat(spec),
             super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
   that.get_name = function (n) {
    return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby'; return that;
    }
  }
```

I am confused by the coma after cat(spec) in line 2. What does the line do exactly? (line 2 +line 3)
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just a shortcut for declaring two variables in one statement, it is equivalent to this:

```
var that           = cat(spec);
var super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```

The [comma is actually an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

A `var` statement is made up of one or more expressions of the form:

```
varname [= value]
```

where the square brackets indicate an optional component. The general [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) looks like this:

> var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [, varname3 ... [, varnameN]]]];

You'll usually only see the comma operator used in `var` statements and [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for(var i = 0, x = complicated_array[0]; i < complicated_array.length; x = complicated_array[++i])
```

but it can be used in other places.

Comment: `var x = y;` is a statement but it *contains* an expression (`y`). However, expressions inside var statements cannot contain the comma operator.

Comment: @Šime: But the entire statement is not an expression so I'm a little uncertain about how to properly explain such details to a beginner. Is my latest updated a bit clearer/more-accurate?

Answer (score 3):

It lets you declare another variable. It's equivalent to the following:

```
var that = cat(spec);
var super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```

See the [`var` statement docs @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 2):

The indentation is wrong, it should be:

```
var that = cat(spec),
    super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```

It is the same as saying:

```
var that = cat(spec);
var super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```